# Dividing polynomials on all terms

Tags: polynomials

Can you please explain why the following operation is wrong:

Expression:
$2 [(x+8) + x] = 208$

Operation: To remove the $  2$, divide both sides by $2$. The $ 2$ cancels out on the left. This leaves us with:

$ (x + 8) + x = 104$

The above operation is incorrectly performed. Could you please explain how it should be performed, and what algebraic rule or principle am I not following correctly? Thank you.

Comment: It is absolutely right

Comment: Yup, perfectly cromulent. Who said it was wrong?

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression that I would have to divide both term (x+8) by 2, and also term x by 2. I agree now that what is above, is correct.

Comment: If it was $2(x+8)+x$, instead, then you wouldn't be able to just get rid of the two like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not incorrect. In fact, if you continue on this path, we get

$$2x+8 = 104 \implies x = \frac{104-8}{2} = 48$$

If we substitute this value into the original expression, we get

$$2((48 + 8) + 48) = 2\cdot 104 = 208$$

which is what we started with.